# How can I call a function random inside other function in prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

I'm trying to call the random function inside another function. For example I want to do this `assert(fact(random()).` But it does not work. How can I insert a random number this way? Thanks.

Comment: Prolog doesn't work this way. What are you actually going to obtain? What's your *goal*?

Comment: What prolog interpreter are you using? How is `random()` defined? `random()` isn't normal Prolog syntax. If you use `random/1`, you can do, `random(X), assertz(fact(X)).`

Comment: Just guessing: do you want to set the seed? See [the SICStus manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest/html/sicstus/lib_002drandom.html).

Comment: I'm using SWI-Prolog, but thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In prolog there is no concept of functions like you are trying to do in your code. You should do:

```
random(N), assert(fact(N))
```

I recommend reading at least first two chapters [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pageid=online) to better understand search and unification.

Comment: Thanks bro, I thought that I could do that